# Number of Laurent monomials of n variables with degree at most d

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory, polynomials, additive-combinatorics, laurent-polynomials

**Introduction:** We have a question of how to calculate the number of $n$-variables Laurent monomials of degree at most $d$.

**For example:** If $n=2$, $d=2$ then we have 19 monomials, which are:
$x^{-2}$, $x^{-2}y$, $x^{-2}y^2$,
$x^{-1}y^{-1}$, $x^{-1}$, $x^{-1}y$, $x^{-1}y^2$,
$y^{-2}$, $y^{-1}$, 1, $y$, $y^{2}$,
$xy^{-2}$, $xy^{-1}$, $x$, $xy$,
$x^2y^{-2}$, $x^2y^{-1}$, $x^2$. They correspond to the following 19 pairs of powers: $(-2,0)$, $(-2,1)$, $(-2,2)$,
$(-1,-1)$, $(-1,0)$, $(-1,1)$, $(-1,2)$,
$(0,-2)$, $(0,-1)$, $(0,0)$, $(0,1)$, $(0,2)$,
$(1,-2)$, $(1,-1)$, $(1,0)$, $(1,1)$,
$(2,-2)$, $(2,-1)$, $(2,0)$.

So how about, e.g., $n=4$, $d=4$ ?

**Formulation:**
Let $n,d\in\mathbb N$. Let
\begin{align*}
\Omega(n,d) &= \{\alpha\in\mathbb N^n: \alpha_1+\dotsb+\alpha_n \leq d\},\\
\Gamma(n,d) &= \Omega(n,d) + \Omega(n,d),\\
\Delta(n,d) &= \Omega(n,d) - \Omega(n,d).
\end{align*}
Then, the elements of $\Delta(n,d)$ correspond to the tuples of powers of the monomials.

The cardinality of $\Omega(n,d)$ is well-known to be $\binom{n+d}{n}$. The cardinality of $\Gamma(n,d)$ can be shown to be $\binom{n+2d}{n}$. However, is there a formula to compute the cardinality of $\Delta(n,d)$ ?

**Some results:** We did some attempts and got that
\begin{align*}
|\Delta(n,1)| &= n(n+1)+1,\\
|\Delta(1,d)| &= 2d+1,\\
|\Delta(2,d)| &= (2d+1)^2 - d(d+1),\\
|\Delta(3,d)| &= (2d+1)^3 - \frac{7}{3}d(d+1)(2d+1),\\
|\Delta(4,d)| &= (2d+1)^4 - \frac{1}{12}d(d+1)(157d^2+157d+46).
\end{align*}
We still haven't found a way to calculate $|\Delta(n,d)|$ in general. By definition of $\Delta(n,d)$ as above, I think we may have a geometric approach. An orientable suggestion would be nice.

Comment: If you pad your monomials with an extra variable to make the total degree zero, then you are looking at the lattice points in the convex hull of the $\binom{n+1}{2}$ vectors $d(e_i - e_j)$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq n+1$. Some people call this the "$A_n$ root polytope". (Other people use the same name for just the convex hull of $e_i - e_j$ for $1 \leq i < j \leq n+1$.) So keywords worth trying are "root polytope" and "Erhart polynomial", but I didn't find anything quickly.

Comment: It appears that $|\Delta(n,n)| = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k}^2 {n+k \choose k}$ - I used your formulas to find https://oeis.org/A005258.  Furthermore your sequences $|\Delta(2, d)|, |\Delta(3, d)|, |\Delta(4, d)|$ are in the OEIS as https://oeis.org/A003215, https://oeis.org/A005902, and https://oeis.org/A008384, described as the "crystal ball sequence for A_n lattice" with n = 2, 3, 4.  I don't know what the "crystal ball sequence" is but maybe this rings a bell for someone.

Comment: The term "crystal ball sequence" is from Conway and Sloane https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/10.1098/rspa.1997.0126 . I believe that in this case it simply is the number of vectors which can be written as the sum of $\leq d$ vectors of the form $e_i - e_j$ for $1 \leq i, j \leq n+1$.

Comment: @SamHopkins It's just the definition. Consider Laurent monomials $X=x_1^{a_1}\ldots x_n^{a_n}$, where the exponents $a_1,\dots,a_n$ are integers. Then the degree is defined by $\textrm{deg}(X)=\textrm{max}\{\sum_{a_i>0}a_i, -\sum_{a_i<0}a_i\}$.

Comment: @SamHopkins: Somehow, to me the definition is still adapted with the usual notion. Consider the usual polynomial ring $\mathbb R[x]$ with indeterminate $x$. The usual monimials are the powers of indeterminate, i.e., $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots$ Their degrees are the powers as we all known. (Continue)

Comment: Now, consider the ring of Laurent polynomials $\mathbb R[x,x^{-}]$ with indeterminates $x$ and $x^{-}$. Again, the monimials are the powers of indeterminates, i.e., $1,x,x^2,x^3,\ldots$, and $x^{-1},x^{-2},x^{-3},\ldots$. So, their degrees are also defined by their "powers", e.g., degree of $x^{-3}$ is 3 since $x^{-3}$ is in fact the power 3 of the indeterminates $x^{-}$.
So, the definition for the case $n$-variables is adapted thereby.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One such formula is
$$\sum_{p=0}^n \binom{n}{p} \binom{d}{p} \binom{d+n-p}{n-p}.$$
To derive this, let $P \subseteq [n]$ be the set of variables with positive exponents and let $p = |P|$. There are $\binom{n}{p}$ ways to choose $P$. After choosing $P$, we must choose a monomial in $\{ x_i \}_{i \in P}$ of degree $\leq d$ where each variable has degree $\geq 1$; there are $\binom{d}{p}$ ways to do this. And we must choose a monomial in $\{ x_i \}_{i \in [n] \setminus P}$ of degree $\leq d$ where each variable has degree $\geq 0$; there are $\binom{d+n-p}{n-p}$ ways to do this. I think this is equivalent to Ira Gessel's formula in the comment below.

My previous answer is preserved below the line:

---

One such formula is 
$$\sum_{\substack{0 \leq p,q \leq d\\ p+q \leq n}} \binom{n}{p,q} \binom{d}{p} \binom{d}{q}$$
where $\binom{n}{p,q}$ is the trinomial coefficient $\tfrac{n!}{p! q! (n-p-q)!}$.

To see this, let $P$ and $Q \subset [n]$ be the sets of variables whose exponents are positive and negative. To choose a monomial in your set, first choose the index sets $P$ and $Q$, which we can do in $\binom{n}{|P|,|Q|}$ ways. Then choose two monomials, one in the variables $\{ x_i \}_{i \in P}$, and one in the variables $\{ x_j \}_{j \in Q}$, where each variable occurs to degree $\geq 1$ and the total degree is $\leq d$. The number of monomials in $p$ variables where each variable occurs to degree $\geq 1$ and the total degree is $\leq d$ is $\binom{d}{p}$. (Note that this is even correct when $d<p$.)

This isn't a particularly nice formula, but I don't see how to simplify it more. (EDIT: But Ira Gessel did; see his comment below.) Note that it is manifestly a polynomial in $d$, for fixed $n$.

Comment: You can evaluate the sum on $p$ to get $$\sum_q \binom{n}{q}^2\binom{n+d-q}{n},$$ which agrees with Michael Lugo's formula.

Comment: Many thanks for the ideas, they're very clever and helpful @David E Speyer